# Default.aspx (Reference Error: AddItem is not defined)

Tags: javascript, client-object-model

So I'm trying to push through learning how to code in the SharePoint environment. I created a script in a text file that i'm calling through a content editor webpart. When I debug the page using FireBug in Firefox I get the following error.

> "ReferenceError: AddItem is not defined"

from the default.aspx page in my SP site. Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks. Below is my code.

```
<SharePoint:FormDigest runat=”server” />
<script src=”/_layouts/SP.js” type=”text/ecmascript”></script>
<script type=”text/javascript”>

function AddItem()
{
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(‘Test List’);

var listItemCreationInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
var newItem = list.addItem(listItemCreationInfo);
newItem.set_item(‘Title’, ‘SPUser’);

newItem.update();
context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.success),                Function.createDelegate(this, this.failed));
}
function success() {
alert(‘Added!’);
}
function failed(sender, args) {
alert(‘failed. Message:’ + args.get_message());
}

</script>

<div>
    <button type="button" onclick="AddItem()">Add List Item To SharePoint</button>
   </div>
```

Comment: try `onclick="javascript:AddItem();"`

Comment: This isn't working in a content editor web-part. I'll try throwing it directly in the web page....Getting same error